# Eclipse hangs when trying to copy variables

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on the ADT eclipse environment. During debugging, there is one List object, which say has 50 items of a class. In the variables window, if i expand all of them, select them all and press CTRL+C, to copy and paste into excel then Eclipse hangs.
After about 15 mins or so it comes back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a debug print and copying from it?